# AQL: (why) are document functions like HAS, UNSET not working?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I try to use document functions like HAS, UNSET etc. (hopefyully) like they are described in the documentation. Unofortunately the lead to Syntax error 1501. I also see that they do NOT get highlighted in the AQL editor like the other signal words do.

Here is one example (which I also tested on the tutorial server):

```
FOR u IN users
    LIMIT 1
    UNSET(u, "birthday")
RETURN u
```

Does anybody sees what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AQL function cannot appear on the top-level of an AQL. The only things allowed on the top-level are statements such as `FOR`, `FILTER`, `RETURN`, `LET`, `COLLECT`, `SORT`, `INSERT` etc.
If a function should be executed, it's return value should be captured inside a `LET` statement for further processing, or, if no further processing is required, the function can be called in a `RETURN`s expression, e.g.

```
FOR u IN users
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN UNSET(u, "birthday")
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, OK ... after writing this I got it: One has to assign this to something. e.g.

```
FOR u IN users
    LIMIT 1
    LET tmp = UNSET(u, "birthday")
RETURN tmp
```

Sorry for posting it ... but I keep it in, maybe other beginners do the same mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for other users: The UNSET function does not actually replace the document in the collection. To do this, you need to run

```
FOR u IN users
    LIMIT 1
    LET u_new = UNSET(u, "birthday")
    REPLACE u WITH u_new IN users
```